# Is it normal that computer controlled characters in LEGO Star Wars III do not fight?

Tags: lego-star-wars-3-the-clone-wars

Is it normal that the characters that may be controlled in-game don't fight, when a player isn't switched to them?  (For example Anakin, when you're playing as Kenobi in the prologue.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is normal, in all of the various LEGO games.  The computer controlled characters will only do something when it is absolutely required in order to move the game forward (such as switches that have to be pulled at the same time).

They will not fight.  If you play single player it is completely up to you to win the battles.

Comment: I recall that in Lego Star Wars some of the computer controlled characters at least pretended to fight, but they definitely never caused actual damage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's normal! There are some characters that can't fight (exemple: C3PO, Anakin, etc.)

[Here's a list of all characters and their abilities](http://swgames.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Star_Wars:_The_Complete_Saga_Characters). This list came from Lego Star Wars: The Complete Saga, but the majority of the characters are the same.

Look the "Weapon" column and all the characters that have "none" can't fight!

Comment: Thanks, but to clarify, in the LSWIII prologue, Anakin has a light saber. A few missions later, when playing with Jar Jar and two clones, the clones are armed but as long as I am not directly controlling them, they aren't doing anything at all, not even dodging incoming projectiles.

Comment: Okay! I misunderstood the question in this case! Berkan Jason's response is that you need!